# How can receive data from usb barcode Scanner in Form_KeyPress Event and put it in a textbox Automatically?

Tags: c#

i have an application with C# , and i need to get data from barcode scanner and Recive it in Form_KeyPress Event and put it in a textbox automatic .

Comment: You'll need some API/interface to talk to your scanner. There might be some generic library for this (look around; never tried it) or there might be some SDK belonging to your actual hardware. There isn't any generic approach to be used just utilizing standard.net stuff as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
private string barcode = string.Empty;

private Form_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (ev.KeyChar == '\r')
    {
        textBox.Text = barcode;
        barcode = string.Empty;
    }
    barcode += e.KeyChar
}
```

Comment: thank you . i want save the input from barcode scanner in a varibale?
how can do that ? in Form_KeyPress Event .

Comment: `barcode += e.KeyChar` puts the data in it. When barcode ends, textBox.Text recive all data. The problem here is that you focused on another controls than form and you do not recive FormKeyPress on form

Comment: i don't focused another controls , and this code not work with me,how can recive FormKeyPress on form ???

Comment: if you delete all control from form. It will work. You can use hooking into the Windows message loop. But not good idea too. The best way to use TextBox as input reciver

Answer (score 1):

Barcode scanner working like keyboard. Open text document and read text with barcode. If it is working try same on textbox. texbox will active in that time. and you can use textchange event.

Comment: thank you for reply .but i need to work without textbox . i want to receive the Returned Data in the Form_KeyPress Event .

Comment: last letter of barcode will be "\r\n". It help you to find out that input ends.